# Множество проверок, множество запросов

Tags: php, sql

**Условия**: как минимум 1, как максимум 3 строки, где `userid=$_SESSION['id']`; наличие для этих строк в столбцах `active` значений 1, 2 или 3 (обязательно все три, без повторений).

**Задача**: узнать, имеется ли в БД для этих строк значения `active` = 1, 2 или 3. Если какое-либо из значений отсутствует, записать их по порядку (сортировка -
 значения столбца `level` по убыванию), затем редирект. Если все значения присутствуют, сделать новую проверку по `level` и если порядок строк при сортировке по `lvl` изменился, перезаписать значения (1, 2, 3).

**Пробный код**:

```
$check_main=$mysqli->query("SELECT `active` FROM `characters` WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND (`active`='1' OR `active`='2' OR `active`='3')"); 
// пытаемся узнать, есть ли значения 1, 2 или 3
$check_main=$check_main->fetch_assoc();
if($check_main_second==false) {
// если отсутствуют, внесение
    $select_char=$mysqli->query("SELECT `level` FROM `characters` WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY `level` DESC LIMIT 1,1");
    $select_char->fetch_assoc();
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `characters` SET `active`='1' WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND `level`='".$select_char."'");
    $select_char=$mysqli->query("SELECT `level` FROM `characters` WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY `level` DESC LIMIT 2,2");
    $select_char->fetch_assoc();
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `characters` SET `active`='2' WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND `level`='".$select_char."'");
    $select_char=$mysqli->query("SELECT `level` FROM `characters` WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['id']."' ORDER BY `level` DESC LIMIT 3,3");
    $select_char->fetch_assoc();
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `characters` SET `active`='3' WHERE `userid`='".$_SESSION['id']."' AND `level`='".$select_char."'");
    exit(redirect("../URL"));
}
```

Страшный код, при котором невозможна конвертация в строку, а также отсутствует проверка при наличии значений. Много условий, как это выполнить ума не приложу.

Comment: что-то я не понял ничего

Answer (score 0):

> наличие ... в столбцах active значений 1, 2 или 3 (обязательно все три, без повторений)

Если список возможных значений active исчерпывается этими значениями, то

```
HAVING COUNT(active) = 3
   AND SUM(DISTINCT active) = 6
```

Если нет, то второе условие усложнится до

```
   AND SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN active IN (1,2,3) THEN active END) = 6
```